# Need Android Achievement Ideas

Tags: android

I'm looking into creating a simple (pointless really) Android App/System that keeps track of various things and gives you points for them. Points could possibly be spent unlocking more achievements, or something along those things. The only thing is I'm having a hard time coming up with things that are feasible to track.
I know there are a number of things you can detect for so far using the different EventListeners, but that's all specific per achievement.
So what I'm looking for from you guys, is just general ideas of what you could possibly track (REASONABLY) on Android to use in this.

The list I have so far (Not set in stone or coded, merely ideas):

```
+The Basics
    -Open 10 unique apps
+Around the World
    -"Check In" to 5 different locations (GPS)
+Time Traveler
    -Obtain 88 miles an hour
+Energizer
    -Recharge your phone for 1000 hours
+Forever Alone
    -Do not receive a call or text for 5days
```

Comment: That's interesting, but I'am not sure, that this kind of question is [appropriate](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

If you can implement a fall detection algorithm using the sensors:

```
+Clumsy
    -Dropped the phone 5 times.
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
+ Talkative 
   - Sent 100 texts a day or had 1 hour long converstions

+ Cool Kid on the block
   - 500+ contacts added

+ Stalker (or Friend zoned) 
  - Calls a number more than 20 times a day with no reply from it. 

+ Socially awkward penguin 
  - 5 missed calls from different numbers, not returned.  (use Call log)

+ Geek 
  - 100 apks installed (Use Package Manager) 

+ Troll 
  - Makes a lot of missed calls, or disconnects calls. (Listen to phone state events) 

+ Hipster 
  - Listens to weird music. (Use echonest API's to analyze the music files on the SD card)
```

---

Also : [4 Square integration](https://developer.foursquare.com) perhaps?

Your app will be a bit too heavy on the battery.